# Plotting the density of the sum of two random variables in SymPy

Tags: python, plot, sympy

I would like to make and plot a mixed random variable with sympy.

I have a Gaussian mixture of two evenly weighted normal distributions, one with a mean of 1, and one with a mean of 2.

```
from sympy.stats import Normal
mixed = 0.5 * Normal('n1', 1, 1) + 0.5 * Normal('n2', 2, 1)
E(mixed1)

Out: 1.5
```

This is correct, but I can't plot this distribution:

```
x = symbols('x')
sp.plot(mixed(x), x)

 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-a1c8047b8c4a> in <module>()
----> sp.plot(mixed(x), x)

TypeError: 'Add' object is not callable
```

When I try to make it a density, I get a long error ending in

```
sp.plot(density(mixed1)(x), x)
...
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'reprec' referenced before assignment
```

Any ideas on why the plotting feature doesn't like the sum here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `mixed(x)` throws an error is by design. RandomSymbol objects are not callable (i.e., cannot be treated as functions), and neither are their sums. Plotting `density(mixed)(x)` is the correct approach. But being correct does not always imply being successful.

With the parameter `evaluate=False` you will see that SymPy sets up a reasonable integral for the density:

```
density(mixed, evaluate=False)(x)
```

The problem is evaluating it, which fails for your example. But this can be fixed by using rational numbers instead of floating point numbers like 0.5.

```
mixed = Normal('n1', 1, 1) / 2 +  Normal('n2', 2, 1) / 2
```

The chances of successful integration are greater when you have rational numbers. And indeed, the following works:

```
from sympy.stats import *
mixed = Normal('n1', 1, 1) / 2 +  Normal('n2', 2, 1) / 2
x = symbols("x")
d = density(mixed)(x)
```

The formula for density looks complicated, but after simplification `d = d.simplify()` it is exactly what one would expect:

```
exp(-x**2 + 3*x - 9/4)/sqrt(pi)
```

Finally, `plot(d, (x, -3, 5))` gives

[image: plot]

Comment: aha! Thanks for the tip on rational numbers!